# Load Spring Context without using Web-components

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a multi-layered architecture containing two presentation layers (Spring MVC and wicket) connecting to one business layer. The business layer is based on Spring and should be accessed via RMI. So far so good.

My question is how do I load the Spring context in my business layer without using Spring Web (e.g. WebApplicationInitializer)? I want to keep it simple and I don't want to mix it with frontend components.

Comment: He design the business-layer as a web-project. So every actor is a web-project. But he likes the business-web-project to not integrate spring into the servlet-container.

Answer (score 0):

As you see [here](http://www.vectorpublish.net/svn/Vectorpublish/trunk/Start/src/main/java/net/vectorpublish/desktop/vp/Startup.java):

```
context = new VectorPublishApplicationContext();
```

Where simply the context is [like this](http://www.vectorpublish.net/svn/Vectorpublish/trunk/Start/src/main/java/net/vectorpublish/desktop/vp/VectorPublishApplicationContext.java):

```
final class VectorPublishApplicationContext extends AnnotationConfigApplicationContext {
```

Regards

Comment: How is AnnotationConfigApplicationContext called? Its not a standalone pgroamm having a main() method...

Comment: Yes, but I dont have a main class. Its a web project :-)

Comment: @OtisOttington Why do you design the business-layer as a web project?

Comment: Is there a better way to use Spring in that context?

Comment: @OtisOttington Indeed! Start with a simple hello-world, instanticate your ACAC and you will need no servlet-container. Place it as a jar and call `java -jar yourjar.jar` on the server.

Comment: Wait, I don't understand. I place a jar, having a simple java app (with static main() ?!) that loads my Spring context containing RMI functions, etc., in the lib folder of my server and start the app manually?

Comment: @OtisOttington Yes and No. "the lib folder of my server" let me think you mean a tomcat or a websphere or a jetty or a jboss or a liferay or any other web-container. *You do not need theese web-containers*, so you have no lib-folder! The only thing you need is a Java.